# TypeError: this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have the following component:

```
import Firebase from '../Firebase/firebase';
function SignIn() {

    const[email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const[password, setPassword] = useState('');

    async function onSignIn() {
        try {
            await Firebase.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);   
            this.props.history.push('/start');
        } catch(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }
```

Here is my firebase class:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration

  class Firebase {
      constructor() {
          app.initializeApp(config);
          this.auth = app.auth;
      }


      doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
        return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      }


      logout() {
        return this.auth.signOut();
      }

      async register(name, email, password) {
        await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        return this.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
          displayName: name
        });
      }
  }

  export default new Firebase();
```

Error:

> TypeError: this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

I can't understand why I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

this.auth = app.auth()